# IN array and LIKE Condition using mysql query

Tags: mysql, arrays, sql-like

I have a mysql query as follows

```
"SELECT * FROM `listings`
WHERE `category` IN (".implode(",",$search_category_list).")
OR `title` LIKE '%".$search_for."%'
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10"
```

It gives result for first condition only. I'm not getting result from second condition. But if I remove the first condition and run the query, i.e

```
"SELECT * FROM `listings`
WHERE `title` LIKE '%".$search_for."%'
ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 10"
```

it works fine.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: this kind of stuff begs for a bound statement.

Comment: Can you please add the values for `$search_for` and `search_category_list`?

Comment: You've got a sort and a limit. This kinda begs the question -- are the id values for any of the title matches actually higher than the id values for the top ten category matches?

Comment: #dinistro the values for $search_category_list = array(123,167,156) and the value for $search_for = "books"

Comment: To troubleshoot this, take off the `LIMIT 10` from your query. Do you still fail to receive any rows matched by the second part of your `WHERE ... OR ` clause?

Comment: #Alex Howansky  there is only 10 rows in the table and 3 have category 123, 167, 156 and 2 titles with "books".[Note that category match rows are different with title math rows. as per tabele the result should show 5 rows ie: 3 for in array ondition and 2 for like condition] but the reults shows only 3 rows. if i run only with Like condition the results show the matching 2 rows

 do u want any more details.

Comment: Post the actual full query that gets assembled by this code.

Comment: $search_category_list = array(123,167,156); $search_for = "books"; $all_listings = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE `category` IN (".implode(",",$search_category_list).") OR `title` LIKE '%".$search_for."%' ORDER BY `sno` DESC LIMIT 10");while ($listing = mysql_fetch_array($all_listings, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ echo $listing['title']."<br>"; }

Comment: No, I mean post the SQL string that your code generates. Instead of calling mysql_query() on that code, just echo it so we can see the SQL that's actually being run.

Comment: #Alex Howansky SELECT * FROM `listings` WHERE `category` IN (123,167,156) OR `title` LIKE '%books%' ORDER BY `sno` DESC LIMIT 10

Comment: If you paste that query into the mysql shell, do you get the expected results?

Comment: yes. in mysql shell it show the correct expected result. but not in the php page

Comment: After calling mysql_query(), echo the value of mysql_num_rows($all_listings) -- do you get the number you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Does the `$search_category` list contains a string or integer value?

If it contains a string, you need to enclose within `""` chars

Example:

```
WHERE `category` IN ("cat1","cat2")
```

Comment: the values for $search_category_list = array(123,167,156) and the value for $search_for = "books" there is only 10 rows in the table and 3 have category 123, 167, 156 and 2 titles with "books".[Note that category match rows are different with title math rows. as per table the result should show 5 rows ie: 3 for in array condition and 2 for like condition] but the results shows only 3 rows [which are from in array condition match]. if i run only with Like condition the results show the matching 2 rows.